# perl DBIx::Class::Schema

Tags: mysql, database, perl, dbix-class

I have a problem with DBIx::Class::Schema, I have created db and then tables: User,Post, ...  . Then I done this in terminal

```
dbicdump -o dump_directory=./lib App::Schema 'dbi:mysql:my_db:localhost:3306' root password
```

Command made lib::App::Schema with Schema.pm and with Result path in it. (With table classes).

This was generated by Schema.pm

```
use utf8;
package App::Schema;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces;
1;
```

And I use schema so:

```
use lib::App::Schema;
my $schema = App::Schema->connect("dbi:mysql:dbname=my_db", "root", "password");
my @m = $schema->resultset('User')->all;
```

In this file a get error

```
DBIx::Class::Schema::source(): Can't find source for User at lib/Local/ThisFile.pm line 26
```

Comment: Are those package names what you are really using? Your Schema is called `Habr::Schema` and you are trying to load `lib::App::Schema`. The `lib` is not part of the module name. It is the _library directory_ that your environment should know about, e.g. by having a `use lib 'lib';` at the top of your main program.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you want to create a package `Habr::Schema` for the schema of your database. You would use the command

```
dbicdump -o dump_directory=./lib Habr::Schema 'dbi:mysql:my_db:localhost:3306' root password
```

and thereafter you can access that module using this

```perl
use lib './lib';
use Habr::Schema;
```

although you must be careful with relative paths in `use lib` and it is always better to use an absolute path so that you may run your code from any working directory

Your full program might look like this. It prints the `id` column from every row in the `User` table

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Habr::Schema;

my $schema = App::Schema->connect(qw/ dbi:mysql:dbname=my_db  root  password /);

for my $user ( $schema->resultset('User')->all ) {
    say $user->id;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, when I paste this code I changed the name of my App and forgot in package. So it is not a mistake, it's my inattention.

Comment: @MiKa: Do you still need help?

Comment: @MiKa: Okay well please run through the process again with `dbicdump`, create a simple Perl program as I have above, and post it as a new question. Please be *very careful* to show your real commands and source files